# MySQL Error 1349 SELECT in SubQuery Issue

Tags: mysql, subquery, sql-view

Having spent quite some time getting my head around how to get the results out of a couple of table correctly I'm absolutely back to square one as the Views in MySQL won't allow me to create one with a SubQuery...

I found a similar thread that states I can write separate views for the sub query but having attempted this I have got myself in a bit of a muddle.

My original query is:

```
SELECT a.*
    FROM (SELECT H.username, 
    H.variety,
    IFNULL(SUM(H.weight),0) - IFNULL(HU.weight,0) As qty
        FROM harvest H
            LEFT JOIN harvest_used HU
            ON H.variety = HU.variety AND H.username = HU.username
            WHERE H.username = 'palendrone'
            GROUP BY H.variety
            ORDER BY H.variety ASC
     ) a
```

Now this works perfectly, but as described I cannot figure out what I need to do in order to convert it to make it run as a view on my MySQL server...

Any guidance or help would be much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saw that the above solution had a SUM missing and also duplicated the results. Using DISTINCT seemed to fix the issue, Here's my answer:

```
SELECT H.username,
     H.variety,
     SUM(distinct(H.weight)) - SUM(distinct(HU.weight)) As qty
           FROM harvest H
                LEFT JOIN harvest_used HU
                ON H.variety = HU.variety AND H.username = HU.username
                WHERE H.username = 'palendrone'
                GROUP BY H.variety
                ORDER BY H.variety ASC
```

Comment: There is basically *no* reason to *ever* use `SUM(DISTINCT)`.  Your results will be incorrect when the two rows have the same `weight`.

Answer (score 1):

Your outer query isn't doing anything, so just remove it:

```
SELECT H.username, H.variety,
       COALESCE(SUM(H.weight), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(HU.weight, 0)) As qty
FROM harvest H LEFT JOIN
     harvest_used HU
     ON H.variety = HU.variety AND H.username = HU.username
WHERE H.username = 'palendrone'
GROUP BY H.variety
ORDER BY H.variety ASC;
```

MySQL does not allow subqueries in the `from` clauses for views.  This is a peculiar limitation of MySQL that doesn't seem to exist in any other databases.

Comment: WOW - I can't believe my epic error! Shows how a long day takes its toll! I'm rather pleased and at the same time gutted I didn't spot that! Thank you very much for your speedy and accurate help. I'll mark helpful as soon as the site allows me to.

Comment: @Palendrone . . . Usually solving this problem is much harder.  You happened to have a useful case where the subquery could just be stripped out.

Comment: Having just looked at why some data is wrong I have found a problem with the above! I know that the end results are all double of what they should be . I've looked into why and found a few explanations but still puzzled on how to resolve without using a SubQuery to allow me the use of this in a view in phpMyAdmin. Any more help would be appreciated - Thx

Comment: @Palendrone . . . Try setting up a SQL Fiddle with sample data that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Posted solution below, the join was creating duplicated rows in the SUM, easily fixed with a DISTINCT. Should I notice the solution I've modified to not be correct I'll set up a SQL Fiddle - Great idea, Thanks @Gordon